# Servererror 500 php register script

Tags: php, server-error

So, i made a website with a login for a friend, to host on his server. Although when testing this for me, it worked all the way, inserting, reading from DB. But when i set it up at his server, it gives an Servererror 500 after clicking Register. This is the register.php:

```
<?php
require("inc/db.php");
?>
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)){
$form = $_POST;
$username = $form[ 'uname' ];
$password = $form[ 'pword' ];
$email = $form[ 'email' ];
$bday = $form[ 'bday' ];


$sql = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, email, bday ) VALUES ( :username, :password, :email, :bday )";
$query = $conn->prepare( $sql );
$result = $query->execute( array( ':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password, ':email'=>$email, ':bday'=>$bday ) );

if($result){
    header("Location:login.php");
  }else{
    echo "There was a problem with your registration!";
  }
}
?>
```

The permissions are set correctly on his side with the connection info... So we really dont know what the problem is...

If anybody could help us figuring this out?

Thanks alot!

Comment: why not you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after `<?php` and check what error its showing exactly?

Comment: i cant see that because after i click register it sends me to this: http://i.imgur.com/AtyCinD.png the same page but then white. this means (servererror 500)

Comment: Then that means there's an error with your server's configuration (you're probably using Apache so its configuration file is `.htaccess`). What is the value of your form's `action` attribute?

Comment: My form has no ACTION attribute assigned, it has a METHOD POST, so when it is valid it would do the header("Location") line

@Anant It happens after clicking the submit button

Comment: Then even if you fix your 500 error, you'll end up with an empty `$_POST` array on the page you've posted the code for, as you're just redirecting to it from another page.

Comment: It is fixed, after i added action="" it is inserting and the login works. Thanks for the Tip Psioniax, and thanks for all the fast comments guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that my form has no `action` so you will never reach to `register.php` code and that's why you are getting that error page.

So add `action` to your form like this:- `<form action = "register.php">`

Also always try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` in your `php` scripts.